# Saving the values of a string to another class and retrieving it

Tags: java, string

I am currently trying to save the values of a string to another class file in JAVA called Memory.JAVA.  The reason why I am doing this is because variables are not saved outside the Try - Catch Blocks.  Therefore I initiate the class in the try catch block by using this code:

```
Memory mem = new Memory();
```

And then when I want to save a string, I use the following:

```
 mem.brother1ID = "Whatever";
```

The reason why I am not creating it as a new String is because in the Memory class, I have already initiated this string.  To test that this has been saved, I have used `System.out.println` to print out the result which in this case was "Whatever" but when I try to get the same result printed out in the same class, I get the result "null".  Does anyone have any suggestions regarding my issue?  Please feel free to comment below.  Thanks!

UPDATE:

Some code posted below:

```
private void searchFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    try {

        Memory mem = new Memory();

        String sql = "select * from userInfo where firstName= ? OR lastname = ?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, searchField.getText());
        pst.setString(2, searchField.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            String placeOfResidence = rs.getString("placeOfResidence");
            String employmentStatus = rs.getString("employmentStatus");
            String currentEmployer = rs.getString("currentEmployer");
            String taxStatus = rs.getString("taxStatus");
            String dateOfBirth = rs.getString("dateOfBirth");
            String mother = rs.getString("mother");
            String father = rs.getString("father");
            String brother1 = rs.getString("brother1");
            String brother2 = rs.getString("brother2");
            String brother3 = rs.getString("brother3");
            String brother4 = rs.getString("brother4");
            String brother5 = rs.getString("brother5");
            String sister1 = rs.getString("sister1");
            String sister2 = rs.getString("sister2");
            String sister3 = rs.getString("sister3");
            String sister4 = rs.getString("sister4");
            String sister5 = rs.getString("sister5");
            mem.brother1ID = rs.getString("brother1ID");
            mem.brother2ID = rs.getString("brother2ID");
            mem.brother3ID = rs.getString("brother3ID");
            mem.brother4ID = rs.getString("brother4ID");
            mem.brother5ID = rs.getString("brother5ID");
            mem.sister1ID = rs.getString("sister1ID");
            mem.sister2ID = rs.getString("sister2ID");
            mem.sister3ID = rs.getString("sister3ID");
            mem.sister4ID = rs.getString("sister4ID");
            mem.sister5ID = rs.getString("sister5ID");
            mem.fatherID = rs.getString("fatherID");
            mem.motherID = rs.getString("motherID");
            System.out.println(mem.brother1ID);
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
            firstNameField.setText(firstName);
            lastNameField.setText(lastName);
            placeOfResidenceField.setText(placeOfResidence);
            employmentStatusField.setText(employmentStatus);
            currentEmployerField.setText(currentEmployer);
            taxStatusField.setText(taxStatus);
            dateOfBirthField.setText(dateOfBirth);
            motherField.setText(mother);
            fatherField.setText(father);
            brothersField1.setText(brother1);
            brothersField2.setText(brother2);
            brothersField3.setText(brother3);
            brothersField4.setText(brother4);
            brothersField5.setText(brother5);
            sisterField1.setText(sister1);
            sisterField2.setText(sister2);
            sisterField3.setText(sister3);
            sisterField4.setText(sister4);
            sisterField5.setText(sister5);



        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

And this is when I try to get the same results of `System.out.println` as before:

```
private void brotherViewButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    try {

        Memory mem = new Memory();

        String sql = "select * from userInfo where id=?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        String IDNO = mem.brother1ID;
        System.out.println(IDNO);
        pst.setString(1, IDNO);

        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
            String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
            String placeOfResidence = rs.getString("placeOfResidence");
            String employmentStatus = rs.getString("employmentStatus");
            String currentEmployer = rs.getString("currentEmployer");
            String taxStatus = rs.getString("taxStatus");
            String dateOfBirth = rs.getString("dateOfBirth");
            String mother = rs.getString("mother");
            String father = rs.getString("father");
            String brother1 = rs.getString("brother1");
            String brother2 = rs.getString("brother2");
            String brother3 = rs.getString("brother3");
            String brother4 = rs.getString("brother4");
            String brother5 = rs.getString("brother5");
            String sister1 = rs.getString("sister1");
            String sister2 = rs.getString("sister2");
            String sister3 = rs.getString("sister3");
            String sister4 = rs.getString("sister4");
            String sister5 = rs.getString("sister5");
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
            firstNameField.setText(firstName);
            lastNameField.setText(lastName);
            placeOfResidenceField.setText(placeOfResidence);
            employmentStatusField.setText(employmentStatus);
            currentEmployerField.setText(currentEmployer);
            taxStatusField.setText(taxStatus);
            dateOfBirthField.setText(dateOfBirth);
            motherField.setText(mother);
            fatherField.setText(father);
            brothersField1.setText(brother1);
            brothersField2.setText(brother2);
            brothersField3.setText(brother3);
            brothersField4.setText(brother4);
            brothersField5.setText(brother5);
            sisterField1.setText(sister1);
            sisterField2.setText(sister2);
            sisterField3.setText(sister3);
            sisterField4.setText(sister4);
            sisterField5.setText(sister5);



        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: The situation as you've explained it so far is very confusing. I think you'll need to post the entire snippet of code that you're having issue with.

Comment: Ok, i'll add to my post.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not simply post some example code?

Comment: There, i've added to it.

Comment: Every time you do `Memory mem = new Memory()` you're creating a brand new, completely different instance of `Memory`. They don't share any state, so any value you set to one you cannot read back from another.

Comment: Also, you're accessing the database from event handlers. That's going to happen on the UI thread. Since you're doing it from a "KeyReleased" method, I assume you're searching the database with every key that is typed? You should look into how to do that in the background instead of tying up the Event Dispatch Thread, although if the database is fast enough, you might get away with it.

Comment: @DavidConrad Valid points - but I think he's a long ways off from having to worry about event dispatching and background threads. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll research that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the value `brother1ID` in your `Memory` object is `null` is because you're using a *new instance* of that object.

I strongly recommend you read up on how object instances are scoped in Java, and what it means to create a *new* instance, versus using an existing one.

For example, when you do this:

```
Memory mem = new Memory();
mem.brother1ID = "1234";

mem = new Memory();
System.out.println(mem.brother1ID);
```

The value printed will be `null`. This is because you're using a *new instance* of that class. If you wanted to maintain the values throughout multiple method calls, your best bet might be to save the `Memory` object as an *instance variable* of whatever class contains the methods you've shown. i.e.:

```
private Memory memory = new Memory();

...

private void searchFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    // Use 'this.memory'
    this.memory.brother1ID = "1234";
    //(or)
    System.out.println(this.memory.brother1ID);
}

private void brotherViewButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Use 'this.memory'
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how I would go about using this.memory to save a variable to the Memory class?

Comment: Added. Again, I think you should probably play around with some small Java classes and experiment using instance variables. This is a very important concept to grasp, and while larger projects can be rewarding to see function, you might be tackling a bit too much at once.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you use this.memory.brother1ID when you could just do memory.brother1ID?

Comment: Simply to be explicit in accessing the instance variable of `this`. It doesn't make a difference in this particular case, but in my opinion it's good practice to preface instance variable access with `this` in case you accidentally have a local variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at here

```
try {

    Memory mem = new Memory();

    String sql = "select * from userInfo where id=?";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    String IDNO = mem.brother1ID;
    System.out.println(IDNO);
```

You are creating the object of Memory and not setting any value.
then you are trying to print  the brotherId which will be null, all String variables will be initialised to null, that is why you are getting 'null'. what you can do is put the printing statement out of the try catch block at he bottom , if there are any records in your database, it will print out the last records brotherId.